# Rasterizing a triangle in Java

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d, rasterizing

Is there a Java graphics library that will rasterize a triangle given the coordinates of the vertices?

I'm trying to analyse the pixel values of an image for the triangular region defined by three points. I have the pixel values in memory, so I just want to figure out which pixels are in the triangle and iterate through them. The order of iteration is irrelevant, so long as I visit each pixel once.

I've done some searching for algorithms, and I think I could implement my own code based on [Triangle Rasterization for Dummies](http://sol.gfxile.net/tri/index.html), or an [Introduction to Software-based Rendering](http://joshbeam.com/articles/triangle_rasterization/), but I'd feel stupid if I overlooked some library that already implements this.

I briefly looked at getting [Java to talk to the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384970/java-gpu-programming), but that seems to be too much hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Polygon Shape to represent the tringle. Then use one of the contains() method passing Point2D or just two doubles params.